unity3d project try to connect HIKRobot's Camera,Crash Happen
After referencing a dll file in unity's C# script namespace, the project crashes when enumerating devices with the following error：
"Type MvCameraControl.MvCCDll/MV_CC_DEVICE_INFO/SPECIAL_INFO which has an [ExplicitLayout] attribute cannot have a reference field at the same offset as another field."
MvCameraControl.Net.dll，
If the field offset value in the source code MVCamera.cs is modified, the camera device cannot be searched and recognized, and the camera model is HIKRobot MV-CH050-10GC
